# ProgressMonitorInputStream will not update in SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, progress-bar, inputstream, progressmonitor

I am trying to make a simple utility from my GUI applications that fetches data from websites. One of the websites, in particular, has a very loading time. So I decided it would best to use ProgressMonitorInputStream to notify the user that my program has not simply frozen. However, I keep running into an issue where it blocks the EDT. To combat this, I added a SwingWorker, but now the program fails to display the ProgressMonitor updating at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
private static String urlToTextLong(URL url) throws IOException{
    final URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection(); //Open connection
    //Adding header for user agent is required. Otherwise, Google rejects the request
    urlConn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", 
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0"); 

    final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>(){
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception
        {
            ProgressMonitorInputStream pmis = new ProgressMonitorInputStream(null, "Loading", urlConn.getInputStream());
            final Reader r = new java.io.InputStreamReader(pmis, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));//Gets Dta Converts to string
            pmis.getProgressMonitor().setMaximum(urlConn.getContentLength());
            pmis.getProgressMonitor().setMillisToPopup(1);
            pmis.getProgressMonitor().setMillisToDecideToPopup(1);
            while (true) {//Reads String from buffer
                int ch = r.read();
                if (ch < 0)
                    break;
                buf.append((char) ch);
            }
            pmis.close();
            r.close();
            return null;
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
    while(!worker.isDone()){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    String str = buf.toString();
    return str;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the length of the webpage is finite. The process completes, but the ProgressMonitor doesn't popup at all. Only a white, unpainted JFrame pop ups, but it never updates.

Comment: Is this code contained by a visual component class?

Comment: I do not follow what exactly you mean, the code is contained in a class which is instantiated in a JFrame.

Comment: Which Thread are you sending to sleep? There's no definition in your code.

Comment: The main thread right? I was under the impression that the point of SwingWorker is that it creates its own thread. (The program cannot advance until the URL is downloaded).

Comment: That's the point then, you're sending to sleep the EDT thread, that's why it's not updating the view.

Comment: How can I make the program wait for the SwingWorker to finish then?

Comment: I can't answer that without seeing more code...but the purpose to use a SwingWorker is to run something outside the EDT thread to keep it running.